# PayPal On-site Integration W/PayPal Providing Shipping Data

Tags: php, paypal, implementation

We're currently using PayPal IPN. We're looking for a PayPal implementation that has this flow:

1.) User logs in at the cart.

2.) We can get their shipping information and email, send them to our payments/shipping page (for selecting shipping option and other order meta data).

3.) User clicks, place order, to place an order and we can tell they paid.

4.) Confirmation page.

5.) All of this keeps them on our site, no client side redirects to PayPal.

PayPal Express seems to try and do it all for you, but this doesn't allow us the level of control we need for step #2. Is there an implementation option that I can use for this flow?

Comment: The closes I have seen is https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/payflow-payment-gateway. however I am not sure if this will work for shipping data, you will have to read up on that, good luck!.

Comment: Ah thanks, I sent this question to our PayPal rep to see if I can get a more in-depth answer. If they don't respond to this question I'll post the answer here myself.
Basically I'm wanting to ease of PayPal Express (from the customers end) but with the ability for them to apply coupons, select shipping options...etc. IPN, what we use now doesn't pass any customer information, which we can hopefully get from a new implementation. A good comparison would be Amazon Payments workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are looking for but still check this link once:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart_upload/